# Remove HD from laptop to transfer data from it with usb cable

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, desktop-computer, sata-to-usb

I have a laptop and a desktop computer, both run on Windows 7 Ultimate, they are in good case, not dead.
I would to copy data from laptop to desktop, if I remove the hard drive from the laptop and connect to as external hard drive via usb cable (that I already have) to the computer.
My question:
I think, it is ok, I can do it, but if I  return it back to the laptop (without deleting or cutting anything from it), does still the laptop work correctly after I insert it at its place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's a common thing to do.

Neither using a SATA/USB adapter nor accessing it from another OS will change/delete anything (unless you actually go and delete files), nor will it magically change the disk's structure in some incompatible way. It'll still have the same bootloader, the same partitions, the same filesystems, and the same files (with the only exception of "Last accessed" times being updated).

(I'm only not very sure about copying files *into* the laptop's disk: if the OS that is accessing it (desktop's) is significantly newer than the OS that's actually installed (laptop's), then newly created files might possibly use new NTFS features that the old OS doesn't understand.)